# Is the format of GUID always the same?

Tags: c#, string, guid

GUID you get something like aaaef973-d8ce-4c92-95b4-3635bb2d42d5

Is it always the same? Is it always going to have the following format

8 char "-", 4 char "-", 4 char "-", 4 char "-", 12 char

I'm asking because i need to convert a GUID without "-" to GUID with "-" and vice visa.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No; there are other formats, such as the format you listed except with braces. There's also more complex formats. Here are some of the formats MSDN lists:

> ### UUID formats
>
> - 32 digits: `00000000000000000000000000000000` (N)
> - 32 digits separated by hyphens: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` (D)
> - 32 digits separated by hyphens, enclosed in braces: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` (B)
> - 32 digits separated by hyphens, enclosed in parentheses: `(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)` (P)
> - Four hexadecimal values enclosed in braces, where the fourth value is a subset of eight hexadecimal values that is also enclosed in braces: `{0x00000000,0x0000,0x0000,{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}}` (X)
>
> *—[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx)*

Comment: I'm curious _why_ GUIDs are rendered in groups of 8,4,4,4,12 instead of (for example) 4 groups of 8 - and why the `"X"` format has such a strange format. What's so special about the last 8 bytes that requires them to be rendered differently?

Comment: @Dai: See [UUID format: 8-4-4-4-12 - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10687505)

Comment: Unrelated to this, how these differ from MD5 hashes?

Answer (score 4):

You should simply rely upon it being 32 hexadecimal characters, there can be a variety of ways to present it. Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) for more information, including a description of how they are commonly written.

For your conversion you should really rely on the static [Guid.Parse() methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx). Using a mix of your example and the ones in [icktoofay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775466/109702), this works nicely:

```
        var z = Guid.Parse("aaaef973-d8ce-4c92-95b4-3635bb2d42d5");
        z = Guid.Parse("{aaaef973-d8ce-4c92-95b4-3635bb2d42d5}");
        z = Guid.Parse("{0x00000000,0x0000,0x0000,{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}}");
```

then for outputting them with or without hyphens etc you can use the [Guid.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) method with one of the established format codes.

Comment: How many characters is it, if it's stored as a string with it's braces ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, GUIDS are 32-character hexadecimal strings such as `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}` (unless they're encoded in Base-64), and are usually stored as a 128-bit integers.  They won't always have hyphens, though.

Comment: That's not to say that can't be saved in other formats, with or without braces and spaces or hyphens.