# How can I generate the same sequence of uuid's in python?

Tags: python, random, uuid

With python's random number generator it is possible to set a seed and get the same sequence of random numbers.

Is there a similar way to generate a same sequence of uuid's (with python's `uuid` module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry, misread the question. The first part was irrelevant.

Yes, Python's random module supports 'reproducable sequences'. See:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility

Seeded UUIDs have been discussed here:
[How to generate a random UUID which is reproducible (with a seed) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186818/how-to-generate-a-random-uuid-which-is-reproducible-with-a-seed-in-python)