# Patching a function in PySpark using MagicMock does not patch in the spark run

Tags: pyspark, pytest, magicmock

I have a unit-test (using **PyTest**) that runs my **PySpark** tests.
I have the normal `conftest.py` that creates **SQLContext**.
I would like to get the same uuid4 in all cases, so I patched uuid4 in my test.
If I call `uuid.uuid4()` from the test funnction, all is good.

However, when I run the PySpark job, that also calls uuid4, it is **not** patched:

My PySpark function (simplified):

```py
def create_uuid_if_needed(current, prev):
    if current > prev:
        return str(uuid.uuid4())
    else:
        return None


def my_df_func(df):
    my_udf = udf(create_uuid_if_needed, T.StringType())    
    my_window = Window.partitionBy(F.col(PARTITIONING_KEY)).orderBy(F.col(ORDER))
    return df.withColumn('new_col', my_udf(df.col, F.lag(df.col, 1)).over(my_window))
```

My test looks like this:

```py
@patch.object(uuid, 'uuid4', return_value='1-1-1-1')
def test_add_activity_period_start_id(mocker, sql_context, input_fixture):
    input_df = sql_context.createDataFrame(input_fixture, [... schema...])    
    good_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    another_goood_uuid = create_uuid_if_needed(2, 1)
    actual_df = my_df_func(input_df)
    ...
```

The `good_uuid` gets the correct value - '1-1-1-1', and so is the `another_good_uuid` but the dataframe's udf version of the function still calls the non patched uuid4.

What is wrong here? Is it something that the `udf()` function is doing?
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just return the string '1-1-1-1' instead of patching? Anyhow you are using it as a function decorator here instead try using it as test class decorator if you want the patch to work every where

Comment: I can't just return 1-1-1-1, as in prod it should generate a uuid.
There is no test class here, just a test function (PyTest) I can put it in conftest.py, but I just simplified the code to make it clear

Comment: Your code is going to behave different in production than in development? This unit test seems useless, you could add a isUnitTest parameter to create function with default value of False and return the string '1-1-1-1' when unit testing but it makes no sense

Comment: Disabling randomization in unit test is pretty standard. Adding isUnitTest is tainting production code. This is one of the reasons why patching exist. Also this is a strip down of the test, to focus on the problem, not the whole test.

Comment: I am not sure about disabling randomization but you can control it, that is why they have tools like Faker. Anyway here is how you mock random uuid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186818/how-to-generate-a-random-uuid-which-is-reproducible-with-a-seed-in-python

Comment: That's nice, but that's not what this question is about - the problem is the mocking of a function called from a spark `udf` funcrtion - uuid is just one such example

Comment: have you figured out the solution for this usecase? I'm running into similar issue and pretty sure that spark's `udf` ignore the mock logic.