# python unique set of unsigned digits using uuid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a unique number (max 64-bit) that most likely won't be reused in the future, or potentially regenerated in the future.

Could that be achieved using:

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4().node
```

which would yield the last 48 bits of the UUID? Is there a chance this 48 bit value could get repeated when calling for its value in the future?

Comment: Why not use the entire UUID?

Comment: What calculation did you do to compare a uuid collision with a 48bit value collision?

Comment: @Barmar the field requires a unique integer, 64-bit max.

Comment: How unique does it have to be? Unique across different machines, or just unique within the same machine?

Comment: The entire UUID4 is unique, you wouldn't take just part of it. It defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Barmar uniqueness across different machines, as it will be stored in a system of record and shouldn't be reusable.

Comment: `UUID4`  is created with `os.urandom(16)` - giving 128 bits of randomness. You could use `os.urandom(8)` which is still pretty good on the uniqueness front.

Comment: It depends entirely on how many numbers you want to store at any one time and what likelihood you will accept for collisions. This is just the birthday problem.

Comment: The full UUID incorporates the 48-bit node ID, to ensure uniqueness across different machines.

Comment: thanks @tdelaney it seems like that could work for my usecase.

Comment: @Barmar does that mean the 48-bit node id is just a random id that is used as part of creating the uuid4 value?

Comment: No, the node ID is not random. It's usually the MAC address of the machine's first NIC. See the output of `uuid.getnode()`.

Comment: @Barmar `uuid.uuid4().node` results in random numbers for me. Docs state that a random 48-bit number would be used if the mac address cant be obtained.

Comment: `.node` is not the node ID. I was also confused by this.

Comment: `uuid4` is entirely random (however, not unique), Versions 1 & 2 *do* contain a MAC address.

Comment: @Barmar: but at 122 bits of randomness is practical for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks everyone who added some suggestions, explained, and added value to my confusion.

Comment: You could clear up the confusion by stating the parameters of your problem: How many numbers are to be generated and what likelihood of collision are you prepared to accept?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, `uuid.uuid4().node` generates random 48-bits. Second, to generate same uid use `uuid.uuid1().node`.
2. Regarding to, "need a unique number (max 64-bit) that most likely won't be reused in the future, or potentially regenerated in the future".
   You can use counter based method. Also, you may try and write some hash function (dictionary) encrypted with md5 or sha256 with respect to your problem.

```
counter = 0

global counter
if counter >= (1 << 64) - 1:
    raise Exception("Max bit value of 64 is reached")
counter += 1
```

3. "Is there a chance this 48 bit value could get repeated when calling for its value in the future?" Yes, there is always a chance that it will be repeated. However, you can try and create dictionary using sha256, but it might be challenging to manage. Still, there is a chance that it will repeat itself. Regarding to hashlib use this post Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186818/how-to-generate-a-random-uuid-which-is-reproducible-with-a-seed-in-python)!

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a probability for a collision, but you should set a limit for a chance that you would accept in your case.

For instance, let’s say that I would like to generate an ID that accepts only digits (1-9), and its length will be 3 digits. When I randomize a number between 0 and 999. When I randomize it at the second time, there is a probability of 1 to 1000 that the same number will be generated again. But when I perform this action 1M times, it will be absurd if collisions won’t appear.

Same for UUID4, but at this case the string will be generated using 122 random bits (other 6 bits are predefined), which means that we have 2^122 as the amount of possible results.

Another thing we should remember is the quality of the RNG (Random Number Generator), which may effect the probability of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

A UUID is just a random number, usually represented as hexadecimal.  If you want a 64-bit UUID, just generate 64 random bits: `random.getrandbits(64)`.  If you want to represent it as hexadecimal, you could use the `hex` function, but there's no practical reason to do this, and the resulting string will take up more space.

The REAL question you want to ask is "How likely is it that two 64-bit random numbers will collide over N records?" This is the classic [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Generalizations).

Here's an approximation of the probability of at least one collision for various numbers of records:

[image]

Note the `1e10`: 0.5e10 is 5 billion, where the probability of collision is 50% or so.  At 10 billion records, you're very likely to have a collision.  At 1 billion records, you are unlikely to have a collision, but it's non-trivial.  At 1 million records, the probability of collision is ~ .000003%, which is like 1 in 10 million or so.

If you're curious about doing this for a different number of bits, here's the approximation I've used:

```
# n is the number of individuals, d is the number of allowed 
#    birthdays
def bday_approx(n,d):
    return np.exp(-n*(n-1) / (2 * d))
```

e.g. `bday_approx(5000000000, 2**64)` is around 50%.