# Is creating a Guid out of an MD5 hash instead of String valid?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, md5

I am trying to implement a method for detecting duplicate files. I have an *MD5* hashing method (let's ignore the fact that *MD5* is broken) as below:

```
using(MD5 hasher = MD5.Create())
using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("SomeFile"))
{
    byte[] hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(fs);
    string hashString = string.Join(string.Empty, hashBytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))); 
}
```

Instead of creating a `string` out of the `hashBytes` can I simply create a `Guid` out of it like so?

```
Guid hashGuid = new Guid(hashBytes);
```

Would it still be valid or will I lose uniqueness?

Comment: They are both 128 bits

Comment: Using MD5 is actually a version 3 GUID: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342058/which-uuid-version-to-use  There are a couple bytes in the version 3 GUID which are hardcoded, but I'm not having any luck finding the reference to the exact details at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MD5 hashes and `Guid` *essentially* both express 128 bits of binary, so:

- plus: you won't lose any uniqueness
- plus: the fact that `Guid` is a value-type means that you avoids an allocation compared to `string`...
- minus: ... but if you're going to *display* it anywhere, you might actually end up allocating *multiple* strings (i.e. rendering the same `Guid` multiple times)
- minus: there is a semantic meaning to `Guid` that won't really be respected/expected here
- minus: `Guid` default formatting isn't the same as how MD5 hashes are usually expressed
- minus: `Guid` endianness is a *mess*, so if you want to get between raw bytes and any text representation: tread **very** carefully; it is **not** what you expect

Comment: Thanks Marc, avoiding allocation was the reason I chose `Guid` but after benchmarking it turned out it's 50% slower than just dealing with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the best idea, but since both values are 128-bits, you wouldn't be losing any data, **assuming that you aren't trying to convert textual representation of the MD5**.

Just convert MD5 bytes directly to GUID, without converting it to a `string` first.

Comment: I am converting the bytes directly to `Guid`

Answer (score -2):

Guids can guarantee uniqueness only if they are generated properly by calling `Guid.NewGuid()`. By constructing Guids from MD5 bytes you gain zero uniqueness. You only store your bytes in a data structure named "Globally Unique IDentifier", that could potentially be not unique.

Do this experiment: create two Guids using the same byte array for both. Do you expect the Guids to be different or equal?