# Longest Version 4 GUID

Tags: uuid, guid

What is the longest (printed length) [version 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47230521/1739000) GUID/UUID when displayed in a non-fixed-width font? (obviously in a monospace font all guids look the same length)

For instance, I want to size a table cell that will hold a GUID, and I want it to be slightly larger than the largest possible value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of testing of which character shows up the longest, I discovered that:

```
dddddddd-dddd-4ddd-bddd-dddddddddddd
```

Shows up the longest in both lowercase and uppercase.

The long answer is that it depends on the font, but in most "normal" fonts (such as Arial, Helvetica, Calibri, etc.), D tends to be the longest character (or a very close second) in both upper and lower cases.