# Java - Apache kafka-client Uuid input differs from output

Tags: java, apache-kafka, base64

I need to specify kafka_cluster_ids, and when testing strings with the `org.apache.kafka.common.Uuid` class' `fromString` method, I noticed that the last character of the resulting `Uuid` differs from the input string, but if you use the string returned by `Uuid.toString` to create another `Uuid`, the input and output are the same.

```java
import org.apache.commons.text.CharacterPredicates;
import org.apache.commons.text.RandomStringGenerator;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Uuid;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomStringGenerator rsg = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
                .withinRange('0', 'z')
                .filteredBy(CharacterPredicates.LETTERS, CharacterPredicates.DIGITS)
                .build();
        String unique = rsg.generate(22);
        System.out.println(unique);  // prints MHAQTegTj687qceJKFx0gB
        Uuid id = Uuid.fromString(unique);
        System.out.println(id); // prints MHAQTegTj687qceJKFx0gA

        Uuid id2 = Uuid.fromString(id.toString());
        System.out.println(id2); // prints MHAQTegTj687qceJKFx0gA
    }
}
```

It's a minor thing, but it bugs me a bit. I'd like to know why that last character is changing. Thanks in advance!

Edit: For reference, the relevant source code from `Uuid`:

```java
    /**
     * Returns a base64 string encoding of the UUID.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(getBytesFromUuid());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a UUID based on a base64 string encoding used in the toString() method.
     */
    public static Uuid fromString(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 24) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input string with prefix `"
                    + str.substring(0, 24) + "` is too long to be decoded as a base64 UUID");
        }

        ByteBuffer uuidBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(str));
        if (uuidBytes.remaining() != 16) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input string `" + str + "` decoded as "
                    + uuidBytes.remaining() + " bytes, which is not equal to the expected 16 bytes "
                    + "of a base64-encoded UUID");
        }

        return new Uuid(uuidBytes.getLong(), uuidBytes.getLong());
    }

    private byte[] getBytesFromUuid() {
        // Extract bytes for uuid which is 128 bits (or 16 bytes) long.
        ByteBuffer uuidBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
        uuidBytes.putLong(this.mostSignificantBits);
        uuidBytes.putLong(this.leastSignificantBits);
        return uuidBytes.array();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apache kafka-client Uuid input differs from output (usage of `toString()` or `fromString()` methods)

Different UUID formats in short, depending to the version of used artifact in Kafka prior to 2.6.x the `toString()` method of the UUID class returned a string in the format `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, where each `x` represents a [hexadecimal digit](https://www.uuidtools.com/decode). Which is most common UUID format in my experiences.
However, from Kafka 2.6.x, the `toString()` method of the UUID class returns a string in the format  `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` where each `x` represents a hexadecimal digit. This format is known as the [canonical](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.1/sqlreferencefornosql/using-uuid-data-type.html#GUID-D2BEE2A1-BF6D-4F4A-8EF4-059A6C8FBAA6)  UUID format, how convert them ? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687505/uuid-format-8-4-4-4-12-why).